# qgis2threejs not showing line styling

Tags: qgis, qgis2threejs

I have generated some vertical lines in QGIS using the geoscience plugin, that consist of several segments in each line. I've generated a number of line styles I want to use to categorize the different segments within each line. They look like this:
[image]

However, when I look at these vertical lines withe qgis2threejs I see only plain black lines. Like this:
[image]

Funnily enough, the grey segment in that second picture corresponds to the only plain black line style.

I know this works with just plain colours, but I have too many categories in my actual project (this is a test) to just use different colours for each.

This is the properties box for the layer in qgis2threejs:

[image]

Is there a way I can use styles like the ones in the first picture or similar (for example, a plain colour with a small triangle of a different colour running down the middle), and have them show up the way I want them to in qgis2threejs?